# Kafka SSL with Python: kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to do secure communication between Apache Kafka server and client. I created the client and server trustores and keystore and did the respective configs by following this link - https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/

This is my following code:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='cylc-vm:9092',
                          security_protocol='SSL',
                          ssl_cafile='CARoot.pem',
                          ssl_certfile='certificate.pem',
                          ssl_keyfile='key.pem')
producer.send('foobar1', b'some_message_bytes')
producer.flush()

consumer = KafkaConsumer('foobar1', auto_offset_reset='earliest', bootstrap_servers='cylc-vm:9092')

for each in consumer:
    print(each)
```

In the above code, when the consumer is trying to connect, it is throwing the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('foobar1', auto_offset_reset='earliest', bootstrap_servers='cylc-vm:9092')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 826, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

The whole objective of removing the ssl args from the Consumer class is to verify whether the SSL Setup is working fine or not. I was expecting some SSL Authenticate exception, however the exception thrown is something else. Did I miss something here or is this the expected behaviour? And does it shows the SSL works here fine?

Thank you.

Comment: Try giving an absolute path to your certs, assuming that the VM address really is accessible and Kafka is running okay on it

Comment: My question is different - If I completely remove the SSL args then I get this issue because the server is configured with ssl.client.auth=required. I don't think the issue is with the address.

Comment: You said "in the above code", which *has SSL info*, so sorry I don't quite understand the question. I'm not sure how this Python library works, though, compared to the Java clients

Answer (score 0):

You should use the port defined in listeners at server.properties. 9092 is the default for PLAINTEXT.